# Which Array Type Should I Choose for Easy Conversion From C# to Java?

Tags: c#, java, arrays, list

i am developing a data access layer in c# which will retrive data from multiple datasources. And i want to use the same DAL layer for the java version of my project.

i wonder the point that i should care about to achive this. For the first, i want to know which type i should use for returning a list of objects. Should i consider using **List**, **ArrayList** or **Array** in c# to achive an easy way of converting from c# to java?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your datasources? Are they databases?

Comment: @NullUserException My datasources are both xml files and sql server database.

Comment: It will depend on what you intend to do with the data (or objects?). Do you simply need to iterate through them or do you need more functionality (like sorting after they are retrieved). Also, will you need the collection to be mutable after retrieval?

Comment: i will probably bind these returning objects into datagrids. So i need a simple listing data.

Comment: The array type used is really immaterial since you are not communicating directly with C# from Java (and vice versa).

Comment: what do you mean by 'converting from C# to Java'? Are you going to port the code or are you going to attempt some kind of communication between the two?

Comment: @NullUserException What do you think which is the most common OOP type for a list of objects?

Comment: @Adam Ralph i will not attempt any communication between Java and C# libraries. i just dont want to do much work when i will develop java version of the current c# project.

Comment: OK. Although I now realise that's irrelevant anyway - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From your comments) It doesn't matter what the most common list type is. Your DAL should return a type that suits the needs of the consuming code. If you are just going to port the code from C# to Java then you don't need to think about 'what is the easiest type to convert'. You just need to use the type which most accurately serves your needs in each language.

Don't let 'ease of porting the code' influence your decision. This may unnecessarily distort your code in both places. IMHO it's more valuable for the code to make sense in each place and spend a little extra effort in porting the code. Having said that, the choice of return type in each case is unlikely to change the effort required to port the code very much at all.

Even if you are going to attempt some kind of communication between C# and Java then the return type from your DAL should still be driven by the above logic and your communication layer should do any necessary translation into interoperable types.

Comment: Thanks. Now i see the logic. However, lets consider i want to communicate the two libraries. Which will be the best type then? IEnumerable<T> or any other?

Comment: It all depends on the method of communication. If via a web service then you would probably serialize your data into XML/JSON and your communication layer would translate from your DAL return type to such a message, making the underlying data type used in the DAL irrelevant. If using some kind of type marshalling interop mechanism then the type used in the DAL should still remain the same, but the type exposed by your communication layer for marshalling may indeed be relevant. However, I would imagine that this route would probably be the cause of a few other major headaches anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing:

- for custom code, `IList<T>` interface is ok
- For api exposed, `ICollection<T>` is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `List<T>`. `ArrayList` is deprecated. The return type of your method could also be be `IEnumerable<T>` so that it won't matter which type of collection, array or list you're returning.

Comment: There is IEnumerable<T> type in Java? I do not know much more about java. So i want to choose the most suitable types that best fits in Java too.

Comment: @Fer: There is an iterable<T> in Java that is fairly equivalent.